# pandas groupby / apply with modified column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe for which I'd like to group by `ticker` and `endDate` and apply a `prod` call to 1 + a column in the dataframe called `ret`.  My group by works, but I'm not able to use a lambda function to add one and also use the group by.  Data sample and current call below.

```
startDate   endDate portName    ticker  optionSymbol    w   rowNum  dataDate    last    ret
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    1   2018-01-10  2.57    
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    2   2018-01-11  2.6 0.011673151750972943
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    3   2018-01-12  3.53    0.35769230769230753
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    4   2018-01-16  2.84    -0.1954674220963173
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    5   2018-01-17  3.95    0.39084507042253525
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    6   2018-01-18  3.93    -0.005063291139240533
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    7   2018-01-19  3.79    -0.03562340966921118
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    8   2018-01-22  4.9 0.2928759894459103
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    9   2018-01-23  5.25    0.0714285714285714
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    10  2018-01-24  5.25    0.0
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    11  2018-01-25  5.73    0.09142857142857141
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    12  2018-01-26  6.96    0.2146596858638743
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216C00087500 0.039721792890262744    13  2018-01-29  7.45    0.07040229885057481
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216P00087500 0.034930448222565684    1   2018-01-10  2.26    
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216P00087500 0.034930448222565684    2   2018-01-11  2.31    0.02212389380530988
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216P00087500 0.034930448222565684    3   2018-01-12  1.5 -0.35064935064935066
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216P00087500 0.034930448222565684    4   2018-01-16  2.02    0.3466666666666667
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216P00087500 0.034930448222565684    5   2018-01-17  1.47    -0.2722772277227723
2018-01-10  2018-01-29  opiv_21_2_atm   MSFT    MSFT180216P00087500 0.034930448222565684    6   2018-01-18  1.31    -0.10884353741496589
```

This produces the desired groupings, but how can I add 1 to the `ret` column and return a product of the result grouped on `ticker` and `endDate`.

```
df.groupby(['endDate','ticker'])
```

This returns the modified column:

```
df.groupby(['endDate','ticker']).ret.apply(lambda x: 1 + x)
```

But applying a `prod` call ignores the previously established groupings:

```
df.groupby(['endDate','ticker']).ret.apply(lambda x: 1 + x).prod()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include prod in lambda

```
df.groupby(['endDate','ticker']).ret.apply(lambda x: (1 + x).prod())
```